# Understanding priors and full conditional posteriors

Tags: self-study, bayesian, estimation

I have a question regarding this problem that we are discussing in one of my classes.

a) I understand that the prior is a beta distribution with the given parameters below, and that if I have a likelihood that is a binomial distribution then its conjugate pair will be a Beta distribution. However, I fail to see how in this example it is a reasonable prior for theta_i, my only guess is that the beta distribution has a denominator that normalizes the distribution and makes the total area under the curve to be 1, hence why it can be used as the probability of success in a binomial distribution. Thus is my assumption correct?

b) For this I have no clue as m seems to just be a scaler for the prior.

c) Will the full conditional just be proportional to the likelihood*prior, i.e. Bionomial*Beta, or is there more that I must include that is related to qi and m?

Many thanks for the help and insight.
[image]

Comment: While I do not think there are "reasonable" priors without the context of the modelling being provided, I would deem the addition of the $\exp(m)$ term a version of a random effect when considering a parameter living in $(0,1)$.

Comment: Our thought was that it was able to just provide a better value for theta, since theta is being represented as the probability that a player will make a clutch free throw.